# Alternatives to Unity panel

Tags: ubuntu, unity

Is there an alternative to Unity (top) panel that supports Mac style application menu integration? I'd like to have a Unity-like user experience on Debian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you maybe want is Global menu?

KDE 5.9 supports global menu.

Xfce, LXDE, MATE (but is GTK+ 2 only): [link](https://git.javispedro.com/cgit/topmenu-gtk.git/about/)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a comparison of the alternatives from 2011. This list is still accurate.

- http://www.junauza.com/2011/09/ubuntu-unity-launcher-alternatives.html

#### alternatives

- Classic GNOME Panel
- [Docky](http://do.davebsd.com/wiki/Docky)

[image: dockey]

- [Avant Window Navigator - AWN](https://launchpad.net/avant-window-navigator/)

[image: awn]

- [GLX Dock or Cairo Dock](http://glx-dock.org/)

[image: glx dock]

Comment: I was referring to the top panel, not the launcher.